# WordPress form buggy on *Some* Android phones

Tags: android, wordpress

Client came to me needing me to create a cash back calculator on their WordPress site http://onetouchrelo.com/

Did it with Caldera forms and seems to work on every device and browser I've tested it on, but the client and one other person at their office say's the calculator doesn't work on their Galaxy S4's. There are other people there with S4's (and any other device for that matter) that it's working fine for. The problem is that whatever the first number is he types, for the incentive it just repeats that number over and over instead of calculating. eg. 3333333, or 5555555.

I've tried removing all of the CSS from the form and just stripping it down to basics, deactivating plugins, all the normal stuff. Nothing seems to fix it for these two guys' phones. They say they're on kit kat and everything else works fine on the site for them. I am at a loss O_o

Comment: Is it not just an issue with the device and not your code? I am tempted to blame the device since you say it is working everywhere else. :)

Comment: That's actually what I'm hoping for :) At this point it's working on **every** device we've tested except these two guys' phones. I wish I had a more technical explanation for them, though :-/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have multiple test cases that work with a piece of software and one device that does not work, your troubleshooting should begin with the device itself.

You mentioned that other devices of type Galaxy S4 are able to use the app. In that case check to see if the OS versions match on the ones that do and don't work. Check that there are no updates needed for the device. Recommend using another mobile browser to use the app like Chrome or Firefox and see if that alleviates the issue.

Lastly, Power off the device and try accessing the web app again.

If it still does not work, then the last resort is to try a factory reset to see if that clears the issue - after backing up their data. But, this seems to be device specific based on what you have mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions—I should have mentioned that we've confirmed they still get the problem after restarting, in different browsers, and both phones are updated and on the same OS.

Comment: Did you find my suggestions helpful at any rate?

Comment: Sure thing! I know it's a very odd problem and appreciate any suggestion I can get my hands on.